# UILabel inside UITableview cell, auto layout padding issue

Tags: ios6, uitableview, uilabel, vertical-alignment

I have following UITableViewCell prototype on the storyboard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhF5y.png

It has three constaraints, left,top,and right distance from superview.
UIlabel has number of lines = 0

When i assign text to the UILabel i have unneeded top padding on some uilabels. For example first cell on the screenshot. How to get that text will be always top aligned?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjwmp.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved issue myself. Seems that auto layout doesn't update label preferredMaxLayoutWidth so this will lead for incorrect formatting. For example when you change your orientation.

So to solve this i subclass UILabel and override layoutSubviews

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
}
```

Comment: This seems to not work with iOS8 anymore. Anyone experiencing the same? layoutSubviews just doesn´t get called.

Comment: My layoutSubviews on my label is getting called.